# html form tag blocks JavaScript from be excuted

Tags: javascript

I am working on a customized html select. It was working fine until I enclosed the table with Form tag. I am puzzled as to how form tag would block the JavaScript. It might be something trivial but I couldn't quite figure out the logic behind it.

```
    <?php

    //initialize menu item array
    $cus_select_input = array('Tx Number',
                            'Search',
                            'Ascending',
                            'Descending'
                        );


    function cus_select($cus_select_array) {
        echo '<select name="cus_select" id="cus_select" onChange="cus_select(event)">';
        foreach ($cus_select_array as $option)  {
            echo '<option>'.$option.'</option>';
        }
        echo '</select>';
        echo '<div id="cus_select_input_container">';
            echo '<div class="cus_select_input_box"><input type="text" name="cus_select_input" id="cus_select_input" size="9"></div>';
            echo '<div class="cus_select_input_cancel_box"><img src="http://localhost/backend/files/cancel.png" id="cus_select_input_cancel" onClick="cus_select(event)"></div>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
    ?>
    <html>
    <body>
    <div style="width:100%; display:flex; justify-content:center; text-align:center; padding-top:150px ">
    <form method="post" name="myform" id="myform">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td style="background-color:#CCCCCC; padding:12px ">
                <?php cus_select($cus_select_input) ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the JaveScript.

```
    <script>
    function cus_select(event) {
        var target_id = event.target.id;
        if (target_id=='cus_select_input_cancel') {
            //clear old value and set the input box to disabled then hide it
            document.getElementById("cus_select_input").value = null;
            document.getElementById("cus_select_input").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("cus_select_input_container").style.display = 'none';
            //activate select and initialize it to the default value
            var default_option = document.getElementById("cus_select").options[0].value;
            document.getElementById("cus_select").disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("cus_select").style.display = 'flex';
            document.getElementById("cus_select").value = default_option;
        }
        else if (target_id=='cus_select') {
            var sel = document.getElementById("cus_select").value;
            if (sel=='Search') {
                //if search is selected, disable select and hide it
                document.getElementById("cus_select").disabled = true;
                document.getElementById("cus_select").style.display = 'none';
                //enable and initialize input box and unhide it
                document.getElementById("cus_select_input").disabled = false;
                document.getElementById("cus_select_input").value = null;
                document.getElementById("cus_select_input_container").style.display = 'flex';
            } else {
                //clear possible input leftover
                document.getElementById("cus_select_input").value = null;
            } 
        }
    }

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out, there were several spots where I used cus_select as ID or name, or function. They are totally different entities though. There were no duplicated names under same type of items. I thought it would be ok but apparently not. The interesting thing was that it did not generated any error (using console) until I enclosed the table with Form tags. I will dig in a bit more to pin point which naming is causing the problem.